# .htaccess remove specific string at the end of url

Tags: string, .htaccess

I have an old site where the URLs are like `/articles/id?PHPSESSID=`

and I want to remove the `?PHPSESSID=` at the end of the URL.

**UPDATE:** I have created a new site and the old is moved to `archive.example.com`. I managed to redirect the old URL to that by adding the following code to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://archive.example.com/articles/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But many old links from Google or FB have at the end the `?PHPSESSID=` which can not be redirected to `http://archive.example.com/` and I don't know the way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Your old site could break.

Comment: I have created a new site and the old is moved to archive.domainname.com
I managed to redirect the old url to that by adding the following code to the .htaccess
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://archive.domainname.com/articles/$1 [R=301,L]
But many old links from Google or FB have at the end the ?PHPSESSID= which can not be redirected to http://archive.domainname.com
And I don't know the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://archive.example.com/articles/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

To prevent the query string (ie. `?PHPSESSID=`) from being passed in the redirect (ie. to remove it) then you simply need to add a `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://archive.example.com/articles/$1? [R=301,L]
```

This effectively creates an empty query string on the target URL. You do not see a trailing `?`. Alternatively, you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on Apache 2.4+

Note that this removes the entire query string, not just the `PHPSESSID` parameter.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work for me

I put 

RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://archive.patris.gr/articles/$1? [R=301,L]

in order the links from Google mostly that they are like

http://www.patris.gr/articles/269431?PHPSESSID=

to be redirected to http://archive.patris.gr/articles/269431

Comment: What actually happens? Are you redirected, but you still see the query string? If so, then make sure you've cleared your browser cache (since the earlier 301s will have been cached hard by the browser).

Comment: No... it is not redirected. If you click on the above link

www.patris.gr/articles/269431?PHPSESSID=

you will see

Comment: But you said in a comment above, "I managed to redirect the old url to that by adding the following code" - the code hasn't changed in this respect, so I'm puzzled why this redirect is no longer working? Where are you placing this directive?

Comment: We have the results from Google from the old site that are like:

www.patris.gr/articles/125279

or 

www.patris.gr/articles/125279?PHPSESSID=

I can manage to redirect the articles without ?PHPSESSID= to go to 

http://archive.patris.gr/articles/125279

but these that have ?PHPSESSID= in the end... no way! 

And I don't know if the problem is that the new site is http(s)

You can try also by clicking the above links